# Similar module for win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData()

Tags: python, linux, pywin32

I was using win32crypt to be able to decrypt Chrome passwords and cookies under a Windows system. But now I need to do the same under a Linux (Ubuntu) system, but after searching with a friend, we've found that win32crypt was only available under Windows and not under Linux systems.
So what I need is to decrypt Chrome passwords and cookies on Linux.

I searched for many hours and I could only find some GitHub repos (that doesn't even work) and some repeated comments :/